# component image does not render within parent component react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, game-development, chess

[image]I am running into an issue where I am trying to push the Pawns component in the second block of code on to a Tile, but the pawn img is not rendering on the Tiles.

The console confirms that the pawn is being pushed as a child of the parent component "Tile", the only way I found to get the pawns to render was outside of the Tiles. Am I missing something, is there a way to get a pawn to render on top of  Tile regardless of the position? (for now)

[image]

```
import PawnWhite from '../pieces/pawn_w.png'
import PawnBlack from '../pieces/pawn_b.png'

const WhitePawn = () =>
{
    return(
        <div className='whitePawn'><img src={PawnWhite} alt='whitePawn'/></div>
     )
}

const BlackPawn = () =>
{
    return(
        <div className='blackPawn'><img src={PawnBlack} alt='blackPawn'/></div>
     )
}

const ENUM_PAWN_TYPE = 
{
   whitePawn: <WhitePawn/>,
   blackPawn: <BlackPawn/>,
};

function Pawns({pawnType}) 
{
   return ENUM_PAWN_TYPE[pawnType]
}

export default Pawns;
```

```
import React from 'react';  
import '../ChessBoard/Chessboard.css'
import Tile from './Tile';
import Pawns from './Pawns';

function ChessBoard()
{  
    const xCoordinates = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "0"];

    const yCoordinates = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"];

    let index = 0 

    const coordinatesBoard = []; 

    const RenderCoordinates = () =>
    {
        for(let y = yCoordinates.length - 1; y > 0; y--)
        {
            for(let x = 0; x < xCoordinates.length - 1; x++)
            {       
                index++;

                const tileKey = `${xCoordinates[x]}${yCoordinates[y]}`;
                
                if(index % 2 === 1) 
                {
                    coordinatesBoard.push(<Tile tileType={"whiteTile"} key={tileKey}><Pawns pawnType={"whitePawn"}></Pawns></Tile>);
                }
                else
                {
                    coordinatesBoard.push(<Tile tileType={"aquaTile"} key={tileKey}>{'a'}</Tile>);
              
                }
            }
            index--
       
        }

        console.log(coordinatesBoard);
        return coordinatesBoard; 
    }
    
    
    return(<div className="App">
            {<RenderCoordinates/>}
            {<Pawns pawnType={"whitePawn"}></Pawns>}
            {<Pawns pawnType={"blackPawn"}></Pawns>}
            </div>)
    
}

export default ChessBoard;
```

```
import './Tile.css';
  
const WhiteTile = () =>
{
   return(
      <div className='TileWhite'></div>
   )
}

const AquaTile = () =>
{
   return(
      <div className='TileAqua'></div>
   )
}

const ENUM_TILE_TYPE = 
{
   whiteTile: <WhiteTile/>,
   aquaTile: <AquaTile/>,
};


function Tile({tileType}) 
{
   return ENUM_TILE_TYPE[tileType]
}

export default Tile;
```

Comment: Look into using  `useEffect()`  -- You can set the state of your object with a hook `setState()` and "listen" for that state change with `useEffect` -- This will re-render your pawn piece (location) in real time.

Comment: You're really not using 'React.js` here to it's full potential .. You're basically using it as a structure .. But not using the "engine" --  You may as well just use vanilla HTML and JS/CSS the way you are attempting to do this.

Comment: @Zak useEffect might work! I am new to react and js, thank you! :)